# matching single quote in regex or in replace() function doesn't work in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, string, react-native

I'm trying to match a single quote (and other characters) in a regex like this:

`/^[a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,.'-]+$/u`

the single quote being at the end of the regex before the "-" character, but impossible to make it work with a "'" single quote character in my string in any way what so ever. so i tried to remove the single quote character like this `myString.replace("'", '')`, but even the replace() function doesn't remove the single quote.

I don't understand because when I test this stuff in my browser it works perfectly as intended but not in my react native code. Thanks if you have any answer for this weird "bug" !

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your problem, I can't reproduce it.

Comment: It looks as if you are tricked by curly quotes, try `/^[a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,.'‘’-]+$/`. Special kudos for knowing where to place `-` in the character class.

Comment: yep exactly, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, it was a problem with the apostrophe characters "U+0027" and the single quote character "U+2019" used by the ios simulator as apostrophe.